Why input do not bind value to variable in this code
I started learning inputs in Blazor. When I try run this code, it doesn't show any errors, but when I enter some text in the input control, then it won't show up in the <h1>...
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>@Meno</h1>

<input class="form-control" @bind-value="@Meno" @bind-value:event="oninput" />

@code {
    private string Meno = "Jano";
}


The previous answers forget to mention that binding like this only works in an Interactive render mode. In this case I am using InteractiveServer as the page exists in the server project. If the page was in the client project you could use any Interactive render mode.
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>@Meno</h1>

<input class="form-control" @bind-Meno="@Meno" @bind-Meno:event="oninput" />

@code {
    private string Meno = "Jano";
}

You are using @bind-Value this looks for a property called Value this should have been Meno. Also you have the case wrong in the event binding this also should be Meno. You can optionally omit the property name @bind="@Meno" @bind:event="oninput". There are scenarios where you may need to bind to more than one property. Not really an option for <input though.

Use @bind, not @bind-Value.  @bind-Value is for binding to components such as InputText.
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

  <h1>@Meno</h1>

<input class="form-control" @bind="@Meno" @bind:event="oninput" />

@code {
    private string Meno = "Jano";
}

See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0

I tried using @bind and it still wont work... I even tried button whitch called StateHasChanged() and it still didnt work...

Then your page is statically rendered and isn't interactive.  Which template option did you select and where did you define interactivity?
